# How to Perform Roundup of Date in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to perform a filter condition in Pig where in I want to filter out the data belonging to the current date , or the current hour or the current week.

In input data I have input as

`2016-01-05 16:59:50,text11`

`2016-01-05 17:59:50,text11`

I am performing a `load` function

```
A = LOAD  '/hoursbetween-poc/input/' using PigStorage(',')  as (time:chararray,colval:chararray) ;


G = FILTER A BY HoursBetween(CurrentTime(),ToDate(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))<1;


dump G;
```

But it is substracting 60 minutes from the current date. I want to filter all records belonging to the current hour

eg:

if the current time is 6.30
the code is filtering everyting before 5.30
i want to round up and filter only before 5.

How to acheive this in pig.

Comment: I guess you could add a hour-field using https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#get-hour and use that for filtering?

Answer (score 0):

**Input :**

```
2016-01-05 10:00:50,text1
2016-01-05 10:59:50,text2
2016-01-05 11:10:50,text3
2016-01-05 09:00:50,text4
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' USING PigStorage(',')  AS (time:chararray,colval:chararray) ;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE GetHour(CurrentTime()) AS cur_hr, GetHour(ToDate(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS act_hr, time, colval;
C = FILTER B BY (cur_hr - act_hr) <= 1;
DUMP C;
```

**Output :**

```
(11,10,2016-01-05 10:00:50,text1)
(11,10,2016-01-05 10:59:50,text2)
(11,11,2016-01-05 11:10:50,text3)
```

Script was executed at 2016-01-05 11:40, as seen in output script has selected records from 10:00 onwards.